# How to simulate specific code part as if previous ones were executed

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, browser-automation

I'm writing automation code by using selenium web driver in eclipse. as per my assumption, whole case execution time probably will take about five minutes but once my code got an error, I have to run it from the beginning after changing the code to see whether changing part is working fine or not. Is there a way to simulate the part being until to fixed code?

Answer (score 1):

Simulate the error outside of the test script, fix it, put it inside the test and run it.

OR comment the code in a manner that the line where the error is happening still works.

For these 2 solutions, you need to know:

1. What the error is
2. What the application does
3. Does this part of the script work without some other parts?
4. Can i manually do the necessary steps for the test on the browser with debugging, so it's quicker to reach the desired step?

You just need to improvise.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to accomplish this, unless of course you code the scenario in such a way that you're able to mimic that state that the application WOULD be in had you ran through the entire test. There's no magical way to make it happen by itself.